# How can I avoid errors around reserved words when querying Access?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I use the code below to log the user into my system:

```vb
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    Dim LogUsername As String = txtUsername.Text
    Dim LogPassword As String = txtPassword.Text

    If txtPassword.Text <> "" And txtUsername.Text <> "" Then
        cmdLogin.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [User Query] WHERE Username ='" & CStr(LogUsername) & "' AND Password ='" & CStr(LogPassword) & "'"
        cmdLogin.Connection = cnnOledb
        Dim DR As OleDbDataReader = cmdLogin.ExecuteReader()

        If DR.Read = True Then

            If DR(0).ToString = LogUsername And DR(1).ToString = LogPassword Then

                'User_ID = DR(2).ToString
                MsgBox("Login Succesful!")
            End If

        Else : MsgBox("Invalid Username or Password, please try again", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel, "Login Error")
            txtUsername.Clear()
            txtPassword.Text = ""

        End If

        DR.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

After clicking on the login button, an exception is thrown:

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

This is the screenshot of the error occur when i click on the Login Button.
[image: This is the screenshot of the error]

This is the screenshot of the table that i am using to do login.
[image: Screenshot of table]

Comment: The *first* thing to do is stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, as well as unnecessary data conversions.

Comment: And to emphasize what Jon Skeet is saying, that is probably the root cause of your problem.  You should not be passing plain-text passwords into an application.

Comment: Yea i'm aware of that but this project is my university assignment and it doesn't require any security concern because it's just a small project. Thanks for both of the concern. Do you guys have any idea what make that error occur?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: That's a slightly different problem, but it's certainly another one. Then there's the problem of not handling the command/connection properly with Using statements, although that wouldn't cause the same kind of error.

Comment: "Yea i'm aware of that but this project is my university assignment and it doesn't require any security concern because it's just a small project." That doesn't mean it's a good idea to completely ignore basic best practices. Why would you want to get yourself into bad habits? *Always, always* use parameterized SQL. To put it another way - if you don't care about security, why do you have a password at all?

Comment: You are supposed to learn at Uni, so please learn things properly. Otherwise you will always find a reason for not going things properly and will cut corners where you shouldn't.

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't learn that yet in my uni, maybe in further semester, but I will try my best looking for it through internet.

Comment: Access password is about as much use as a lock on a screen door....

Comment: *I am sorry that I didn't learn that yet in my uni ...*. Please go out and blame your incompetent prof/tutor. How to create secure and stable SQL queries should be the first lesson in any database course!

Comment: @AlexB. Yes i agree with you that "How to create secure and stable SQL queries should be the first lesson in any database course!" Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments but the immediate cause of your issue is that "Password" is a reserved word in Access so you need to escape it if you want to use it as an identifier.  You already know how to do that because you're already doing it with the table name, which you have poorly named with a space in it.

Comment: Thanks dude! After consider your answer about that "Password" is a reserved word in Access, I immediately go and change the "Password" Column in both my [User] & [User_Query] table to "User_Password". And now it's work !! Thanks dude.

Comment: It will work until someone types a username or a password containing a single quote. Did you try it? What happens when you do it? You have been warned about it in the comments above. Don't ignore them.

Comment: @Steve I tried just now it show error and the application is crashed. So i added a try and catch condition which allow it show error message. Thank s for your idea!

Comment: Nope, this remedy is worse than the illness. Driving program logic using Exception is particularly bad for the performance of your app. I will repeat the suggestion given above by two of the most important authors of this site. **Use a parameterized query.**

Comment: @Steve I will look for it! Thanks a lot!